# How can I reach a remote ssh server through my http proxy (80 port)?

Tags: ssh, proxy

I want to reach a remote ssh server through or over my http proxy. My proxy requires authentication, so I am a little lost.... could somebody give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you setup an HTTP server on the remote side to unmask the HTTP tunnel and turn it into regular SSH again, it wont work. What often works is you putting sshd to listen on port 80 to bypass firewall rules, which is a very different thing altogether and is just talking the SSH protocol in TCP/80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is really restricted to pure http, [httptunnel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel) is meant to tunnel TCP connection through HTTP requests.

Though performance-wise, you'd do much better if the proxy supports `CONNECT`, or if the firewall allows other kinds of traffic - e.g. OpenVPN or [teredo](http://packages.debian.org/miredo).